# What is the entropy of a string?

Tags: string-theory, black-holes, entropy, popular-science, information

In his [*The Black Hole War: My Battle with Stephen Hawking to Make the World Safe for Quantum Mechanics*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6411731-the-black-hole-war) (p. 373) Susskind states that

> the entropy of a string is [...] proportional to its length. Imagine moving along the string as it turns and twists. Each turn and twist is a few bits of information.

(The context doesn't reveal to me whether he is talking about open or closed strings. It also seems to go from String Theory strings to yards of yarn, and back again.)

The statement seems (almost) true for open strings, but I wonder especially about closed strings. If we follow his imagination and move along the string, we know that sooner or later we somehow need to make our way back to the beginning of the string in order to close it. Therefore, we have less degrees of freedom, less information.

So, i) is this something he chose to overlook, or ii) is a correction like the one I am thinking of going to be linear, therefore maintaining the "proportionality", or iii) is something else the matter?

Comment: Was the [tag:popular-science] tag  an accident ? Are you rea;;lly asking for a layman explanation?  .

Comment: @Dimension10 No, it wasn't accidental. I didn't really think about it, but it would be nice to get answers that are roughly on the same level as the book, if possible. Otherwise, be my guest and fire away!

Comment: [Similar question onn stack overflow : )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081105/how-does-the-entropy-of-a-string-of-english-text-signify-low-quality)

Comment: Well, now that I think about it, it seems to be applicable to closedd strings too. They may have less entroopy, but they' are' not going to change the fact that the entropy is proportio]nal [to it's lengpth.